# Quiz Game - IF Statements & Possible Else If?

Tags: java, if-statement, design-decisions

I am very new to this and was wondering if anyone could help me.
I want the code to be able to stop asking questions after the answer is on certain questions. I get it to work on the first ones like the parrot and emu but I can't seem to add others. Please advise me what I am doing wrong.

The code so far is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
* Guessing Game.
* 
* @author O 
* @version 99
*/
public class Quiz
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean answerIsCorrect;

    System.out.println("Think of an animal.\n");

    if(ask("Is it a bird? ", keyboard))
    {
        if(ask("Can it fly? ", keyboard))
        {
            answerIsCorrect = ask("Is it a parrot? ", keyboard);
        }
        else
        {
            answerIsCorrect = ask("Is it an emu? ", keyboard);
        }

    {
        if(ask("Does it live in the ocean? ", keyboard))
    {
        if(ask("Is it a whale? ", keyboard))
        {
            answerIsCorrect = ask("Answer 1? ", keyboard);
        }
        else
        {
            answerIsCorrect = ask("Answer 2? ", keyboard);
        }
    }
    }
    }



    else



    {
        if(ask("Does it lay eggs? ", keyboard))
        {
            answerIsCorrect = ask("Is it a platypus? ", keyboard);
        }
        else
        {
            answerIsCorrect = ask("Is it a kangaroo? ", keyboard);
        }
    }


    if(answerIsCorrect)
    {
        System.out.println("I am good!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Drats! I guess I don't know then!");
    }
 }

 /**
 * A utility method to ask a yes/no question
 * 
 * @param question the question to ask
 * @param a scanner for user input
 * 
 * @return whether the user answered "yes" (actually, whether the user answered
   anything starting with Y or y)
 */
 private static boolean ask(String question, Scanner keyboard)
 {
    System.out.print(question);

    String answer = keyboard.nextLine().trim();



    return answer.charAt(0) == 'Y' || answer.charAt(0) == 'y';
  }
   }
```

Comment: I don't know why this is getting down votes. Everyone needs to start somewhere and while this might not be a question as interesting or complex as branch prediction on unsorted vs sorted arrays, Ozzy needs some guidance and that's what SO is here for.

Comment: @sgcharlie I agree, this question is valid, and Ozzy has demonstrated a minimal effort and provided code.

Answer (score 1):

You seem have an extra pair of brackets in your code (after the initial if statement. You probably want to remove those. Also, you'll probably want to add an `else if`. So, something like:

```
if(ask("Is it a bird? ", keyboard))
{
    if(ask("Can it fly? ", keyboard))
    {
        answerIsCorrect = ask("Is it a parrot? ", keyboard);
    }
    else
    {
        answerIsCorrect = ask("Is it an emu? ", keyboard);
    }           
}
else if(ask("Does it live in the ocean? ", keyboard))
{
    if(ask("Is it a whale? ", keyboard))
    {
        answerIsCorrect = ask("Answer 1? ", keyboard);
    }
    else
    {
        answerIsCorrect = ask("Answer 2? ", keyboard);
    }
}
else
{
    if(ask("Does it lay eggs? ", keyboard))
    {
        answerIsCorrect = ask("Is it a platypus? ", keyboard);
    }
    else
    {
        answerIsCorrect = ask("Is it a kangaroo? ", keyboard);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps. Good luck with learning how to program.

Comment: @Ozzy when you get this up and running you might want to look into using a tree structure for the questions instead of if-else if-else; its structure is ideal for this kind of thing.

Comment: The flow is like a tree , but will Tree Data Structure help the selection(if else nesting) ???
any better solution other that nested if-else for such algorithms ?

Comment: I agree with Shane. A tree structure would be a better implementation, especially if you ever want to read in the questions from a data source (like a database or a file) instead of having hardcoded strings. If you want this to be a serious program, then you should definitely look into a recursive structures. However, I would recommend mastering the `if-else` (and probably `for` loops) first.